# Is there a way to exclude the addthis module's output in the $content variable?

Tags: 7, theming

The `$content` variable in my `node.tpl.php` file outputs some CCK field content, the content body, five star content, and the add this content. I don't want it to show `add this content`. Is there a way to override the `$content` variable to make it not show `add this content`? I can't do this by editing the addthis module's settings, because I invoked the `add this` in another place.

Answer (score 2):

You can unset or alter items in `$node->content` by implementing [hook_nodeapi()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_nodeapi/6) and using the 'alter' `$op`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by:

> I invoked the "add this" in another place

You may want to have a look at implementing one of the following hooks, to remove it from the `$content` variable:

- [hook_link_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_link_alter/6)
- [hook_nodeapi()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_nodeapi/6)
- [template_preprocess_node()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_node/6)